# grep bash alias

Tags: bash, alias

I try to write grep alias exclude log files

```
alias gr='grep -R --exclude=\*.{log,0,1,2,js} "$1" *'
alias gr='grep -R --exclude=\*.{log,0,1,2,js} $1 *'
```

Doesn't work correct

I need to make something like `gr "sometext"`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use arguments (`$1`) in an alias. Use a function instead.

```
function gr { grep -R --exclude=\*.{log,0,1,2,js} "$1" * ; }
```

This should work.

Comment: gr "sometext"
zsh: command not found: sometext

Comment: @ВячеславЛогинов If you are using zsh, why did you tag it with bash?

Comment: usually zsh do same as bash, also i try this trick in bash